# Equivalent definitions of lim sup

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose $(x_n)$ is a sequence of real numbers.
Let $y_n=\sup\big\{x_k:k\ge n\big\}$.

Define

- $\limsup x_n=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}y_n\;$ if $y_n$ is finite and $(y_n)$ is bounded from below,
- $\limsup x_n=\infty\;$ if $y_n=\infty$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$,
- $\limsup x_n=-\infty\;$ if $y_n\to-\infty$ as $n\to\infty$.

Let $\;S=\big\{x\in\Bbb R:\text{there is a subsequence }(x_{n_k})\text{ such that }\\\qquad\;\;x_{n_k}\to x\text{ as }k\to\infty \big\}.$

Then
$$\limsup x_n=\sup S.$$
My question is should we replace $\,S\,$ by $\,S\cup\big\{\infty,-\infty\big\}\,$ considering subsequences that converges to $\,\infty\,$ or $\,-\infty$ ?
For example for $\big\{n\big\}_{\!n=1}^{\!\infty}\,$,$\;S\,$ is empty.

Comment: You don’t replace $S$ by $S\cup\{\infty,-\infty\}$, because then the supremum is trivially going to be $\infty$. Perhaps you mean $S=\{x\in\Bbb{R}\cup\{-\infty,\infty\}\,:\,\cdots\}$, then yes that’s correct.

Comment: Right. In addition to @peek-a-boo's answer, you can define $S=\{x\in[-\infty,\infty]:\cdots\}$ as opposed to $S=\{x\in(-\infty,\infty):\cdots\}$. This notation is well-defined and convenient.